# php get data in my array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a folllowing variable variable

```
$test="<title>This is 1 test | "best"</title>, <title>This is 2 test | "best"</title>,     <title>This is 3 test | "best"</title>, <title>This is 4 test | "best"</title>, <title>This is 5 test | "best"</title>";
```

I want the data in following order, by using array and get raid of **"title** from the beginning and  **| "best"/title** at the end.

```
This is 1 test
This is 2 test 
This is 3 test 
This is 4 test 
This is 5 test
```

Thanks & kind Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$test='<title>This is 1 test | "best"</title>, <title>This is 2 test | "best"</title>,     <title>This is 3 test | "best"</title>, <title>This is 4 test | "best"</title>, <title>This is 5 test | "best"</title>';    
$array = explode(' , ', trim(str_replace(array('"best"', '|'), '', strip_tags($test))));
print_r($array);
```

[Codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3IVA0W)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the variable `$test` isn't valid, you need to escape the double quotes in it or use single quotes for the value.

```
<?php
$test = '<title>This is 1 test | "best"</title>, <title>This is 2 test | "best"</title>,     <title>This is 3 test | "best"</title>, <title>This is 4 test | "best"</title>, <title>This is 5 test | "best"</title>';

$test = str_replace(array('<title>', '| "best"</title>'), array('',''), $test);

$array = explode(", ", $test);

print_r($array);
```